# DAX Refer to previous row within a measure

Tags: powerbi, dax, circular-dependency

Given the data below where Queue2 represent the difference between the Input and Output if the input is greater than the output:

[image]

And the following measure to determine the amount of items in the queue:

```
    queue =
VAR activseq =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( Feuil3[Sequence] )
VAR prevseq = activseq - 1
VAR preval =
    LOOKUPVALUE ( Feuil3[Queue2], Feuil3[Sequence], prevseq )
VAR calc =
    MAX ( Feuil3[Input] ) - MAX ( Feuil3[Ouput] )
VAR result =
    IF (
        SELECTEDVALUE ( Feuil3[Input] ) > SELECTEDVALUE ( Feuil3[Ouput] ),
        SELECTEDVALUE ( Feuil3[Input] ) + preval
            - SELECTEDVALUE ( Feuil3[Ouput] ),
        0
    )
RETURN
    result
```

I get the following result:

[image]

However, I need to achieve the following result:

| Sequence | Input | Output | Queue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 | 50 | 0 |
| 2 | 51 | 50 | 1 |
| 3 | 120 | 50 | 71 |
| 4 | 41 | 50 | 62 |
| 5 | 50 | 50 | 62 |
| 6 | 51 | 50 | 63 |
| 7 | 52 | 50 | 65 |

To achieve this result, I need the following formula:

```
SELECTEDVALUE ( ****Previous row Queue value**** ) + SELECTEDVALUE ( Feuil3[Input] ) - SELECTEDVALUE ( Feuil3[Ouput] )
```

I have tried but I encounter a circular dependency error:

```
VAR prevHourQueue =
CALCULATE(
    [queue],
    FILTER(ALL('Hour Chart'), 'Hour Chart'[Hour #] = prevseq)
)
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either I'm doing something wrong, or your numbers don't add up. This is my running total for excess input (above 50)

```
RT Excess Input = CALCULATE([Excess Input],
                    FILTER(
                        ALL('Table'),
                        [Sequence]<=MAX('Table'[Sequence])
                    )
                )
```

Excess Input is just this:

```
Excess Input = SUMX('Table',
                IF([Sequence]=1,0,[Input]-[Output])
```

)

(Just ignores the first row in the table), otherwise calculates the difference. My result goes {0,1,71,62,62,63,65}

Comment: you're right, I made a typo

Comment: Oh, okay. Was just wondering because most of my numbers were right. I was wondering why one was wrong, that's all.